# Missing parts in Beautiful Soup results

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to retrieve the table in the ul tag in the following html code, which mostly looks like this:

```html
<ul class='list' id='js_list'>
  <li class="first">
       <div class="meta">
           <div class="avatar">...</div>
           <div class="name">黑崎一护</div>
           <div class="type">...</div>
       </div>
       <div class="rates">
           <div class="winrate">56.11%</div>
           <div class="pickrate">7.44%</div>
       </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

but just with more entries. It's from [this](https://moba.163.com/m/wx/ss/) website.

So far I have this (for specifically getting the win rates):

```html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
r = requests.get("https://moba.163.com/m/wx/ss/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
win_rates = soup.find_all('div', class_ = "winrate")
```

But this returns empty and it seems like the farthest Beautiful Soup was able to get was the ul tag, but none of the information under it. Is this a parsing issue? Or is there JavaScript source code that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that your format is incorrect for pulling the div with the attribute. I was able to pull the winrate div with this:

```
soup.find('div',attrs={'class':'winrate'})
```

Comment: I think I still have a problem with pulling all the tags because when I replace my line with the above I get no values/an empty list (if I use find_all). The HTML in my original post was what I copied from the website. But when I print my request, I get only up to the ul tag and none of the div.

Comment: In the code, there is a class of js_list. That would lead me to believe this might be dynamically generated. If so, then BeautifulSoup won't work for you. One way to test is to just request the page and print the contents. If what you are looking for isn't there, then you will need to use a different library.